# Auto Suggestions in Elastic Search after 3 letters

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a search query which does basic search after a complete word is typed in. I'm looking for auto suggestions after 3 letters.
For Example, 
Title- samsung galaxy s4
I want to see auto suggestions after  "sam" instead of complete word "samsung".

Comment: Is this for web app we are not clear about the context of your question webapp, mobileapp

Comment: It should work for both webapp and mobileapp. My backend is in node.js +express.

Comment: you can handle it on client side to only make the api call when the typed character is more than 3 chars excluding space

Answer (score 2):

while the ngram filter works, there is a dedicated suggester for this use-case, called the `completion` suggester, which uses another data structure internal, which will allow you to execute suggestions in the millisecond range, thus being much faster than a regular query use edgengram. Check out the documentation here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters-completion.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an edgeNGram filter for this.

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": "3",
            "max_gram": "20"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_edge_ngram": {
            "filter": ["lowercase"],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and mapping will be

```
{
     "title_edge_ngram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete_edge_ngram",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
    }
```

Or you can use the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) in elasticsearch.
For three character check, you have to do it in your client side itself.